# What is the maximal volume of the torus?

Tags: optimization, volume, solid-geometry

We have a $10 \, {\rm m}^2$ metal plate and we want to construct a toroidal gas tank, as shown below.

[image: torus]

Assuming that all metal is used, what must the values of inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b$ be to have maximal volume? What is the maximal volume?

---

I know that:

The surface area of torus is : **$4\pi^2 ab$**

The volume of torus is : **$2 \pi^2 a^2 b$**

I got **$V = 5a$**, how can I find the first derivative to test critical points?

Comment: Have you heard of the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: I think you are misrepresenting the parameters $a$ and $b$. In your notation, $a$ is the radius of the circular cross-section and $b$ is the radius to the center of the cross-section. Now, you can write $V=Sa/2$, ergo the maximum value of volume will occur when $a$ is maximized and thus $b$ is minimized, which must occur when $a=b$, and hence the donut has no hole.

Comment: @CyeWaldman Yes, I meant V= 5a, if I follow your approach then the shape will be not as required. Can I get the maximal dimensions of this current torus?

Comment: @davinci_07 Unfortunately, I couldn't find λ using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @MahmoodAbed The maximum value of volume as I stated. If you allow $b$ to increase, then $a$ (and hence volume) must decrease. A personal suggestion: You should never input parameter values in the numerical form until the last possible moment. For suppose that tomorrow someone told you that S=10.43 $m^2$?

Comment: @CyeWaldman Thank you sir I understood you very clear and I did solve the question.